# RoomのデータをFlow経由でLiveDataに渡して初期値の表示を挟まずにComposeに値を反映させたい

Tags: android, kotlin

`Room`に保存した`isValid`フラグ(`Boolean`)の値を見て
`true`だったら青の`Text`を表示して
`false`だったら赤の`Text`を表示するような場合を考えます。

`Room`に`isValid`フラグを`true`で保存して再度アプリを立ち上げると
`observeAsState`の`initial値`である`false`を`isValidState`は
取得してその後から`Flow`で流れてきた`true`を取得します。
そのため、一瞬`false`のときの赤の`Text`が出てきてから消えて青の`Text`が
表示されます。
このような場合に、最初から`DB`の値に対応した青の`Text`だけを表示させる方法は
皆さまどのようにされておりますでしょうか？ご存じもしくはアイデアのある方が
いらっしゃられましたら、何卒お知恵を頂けますでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
// Composable
val isValidState by viewModel.isValid.observeAsState(initial = false)

if (isValidState) {
    Text(text = "青", color = Color.Blue)
} else {
    Text(text = "赤", color = Color.Red)
}

// Viewmodel
val isValid: LiveData<Boolean> = repository.isValid.asLiveData()

// Repository
val isValid: Flow<Boolean> = dao.isValid()

// Dao
@Query("SELECT isValid FROM hoge WHERE id = 0")
fun isValid(): Flow<Boolean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`observeAsState`の初期値を無くすと`nullable`型になりました。
初回コンポーズ時は、`DB`からまだ値が取れていませんので`null`が入り
その後に値が流れてきます。
よって、以下のコードで最初から`DB`の保存値である`true`の場合だけ表示できました。

```
val isValidState: Boolean? by viewModel.isValid.observeAsState()

isValidState?.let {
    if (it) {
        Text(text = "青", color = Color.Blue)
    } else {
        Text(text = "赤", color = Color.Red)
    }
}
```